# Detect iPhone5, 5s, 6, and 6 plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Can someone show me how to update the below code to work with iPhone 5, 5s, 6, and 6 +? When I test the simulator for the aforementioned devices, no image is set as the background...

```
UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_Image];
[backgroundImageView setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
[[self view] addSubview:backgroundImageView];
//I EXCPECTED THIS NEXT LINE OF CODE TO WORK TO SET A SEPARATE BACKGROUND FOR IPAD...
UIImage *Image = [[UIImage alloc]init];
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480) {
    // iPhone, iPod Touch
    Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
}
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
    // supposably iPhone 5 but only works for 4
    Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
}
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 1024) {
    // iPad
    Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
}
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:Image];
```

Comment: There are plenty of existing resources that tell you the screen sizes for all of the devices. Please look them up. If you still have trouble, update your code with what you tried and explain the issue you are still having.

Comment: Ok @maddy, then why doesn't my iPhone5 simulator load the image when '568' is the alleged metric to get the job done?

Comment: Does your app include the proper 4" launch image? And is your app running in portrait at the time?

Comment: Yes its portrait mode in the simulator, but I haven't specified a launch image yet..i just need a basic code update. ..

Comment: No, you need the launch images. Without them your app will run like it is on a 3.5" device.

Comment: In what way? I haven't noticed anything out of the ordinary...? You don't mean the launch screen do you? I customized the one in my app a while ago, otherwise I'm drawing a blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    #define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] >= 2.0)

    #define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
    #define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
    #define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    #define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

    #define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
    #define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
    #define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)
```

Then compare in your if statement.

```
UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_Image];
[backgroundImageView setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
[[self view] addSubview:backgroundImageView];

UIImage *Image = [[UIImage alloc]init];

if(IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    }
    if(IS_IPHONE_6)
    {
        Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    }
    if(IS_IPHONE_6P)
    {
        Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    }
```

I don't see why you're doing it this way though.... Is it because your image is becoming distorted based on different devices? Because there are easier and more efficient ways to solve this in IB.

Comment: yeah there is some weird stuff going on. I made the app universal originally while testing it on an iPad mini, but realized I wouldn't have the time to add device specific code for both versions so i just changed it to iPhone in deployment settings. Since then, testing it on my iPad makes the app run like a regular app made for iPhone running on an iPad (thin black frame around the app) but for some reason the actual iPhone devices don't load the images properly so I have to reset some backgrounds but thanks for your answer i'll try it out.

Comment: @zaprogers Cool let me know how it goes when you try it out!