# UIKeyboard not showing in Xcode Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

Yesterday I tested my apps login features on my physical iPad mini as well as all Xcode simulator devices. Bizarrely when I go to retest today, the`UITextField` doesn't popup at all for the iPad Air simulator, the iPad 2 simulator, the iPad retina simulator, the iPhone 5 simulator, or the iPhone 4s simulator. But the keyboard shows up on my physical iPad mini, the iPhone 5 simulator, the iPhone 6 simulator and the iPhone 6 + simulator.

Keep in mind I just tested all these devices not even 24 hours ago with the keyboard working fine. I even restarted my laptop but still the Keyboard doesn't popup even though its been explicitly set as the first responder since I started building this app.

Whats going on?

**Additional info:** my deployment target is 7.1 but I noticed above the simulator reads 8.2. Either way whats going on here? Should I just keep building and hope this is a glitch on my laptop? (I really need a new one anyway due to abrupt crashes) but i can't help but notice that even though I back up my app, there are weird spontaneous changes sometimes at runtime.

Does anyone know the cause of this? (specifically the keyboard incident) Also the most recent changes I made to the app was the answer to this question [Detect iPhone5, 5s, 6, and 6 plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688975/detect-iphone5-5s-6-and-6-plus/29689403#29689403)

Comment: Go to Simulator->Hardware->keyboard or Command+K

Comment: wow that was fast. Thank you. I didn't expect the keyboard to show up on its own after command k + relaunching. Very cool. What do you think caused this? Also feel free to leave your comment in answer form so I can accept it + points.

Comment: awesome. nothing better than a fast answer and an easy fix!

Comment: Command+k switches between UI keyboard & physical keyboard. When the UI keyboard is hidden you'll be able to type into UITextFields using your laptop keyboard instead of tediously clicking keys with a mouse/trackpad.

Answer (score 1):

you can connect keyboard by iosSimulator Hardware menu -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

CMD + SHIFT + K will open the keyboard